# Need Help Creating a Chrome Extension to Replace API Response with 504 Status Code

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Here's a revised version of your post for Stack Overflow:

Title: Need Help Creating a Chrome Extension to Replace API Response with 504 Status Code

I'm trying to create a Chrome extension that replaces an API response with a 504 status code. I'm aware that the extension "requestly" can achieve this, but I want to create my own extension tailored for a specific call.

I attempted to solve this using ChatGpt queryly, but the solution provided didn't work. I'd appreciate any guidance or suggestions from those who have experience with this.

Here's what I have so far:

Manifest:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Fake Status Code",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "permissions": ["webRequest", "webRequestBlocking"]
}
```

Background Script:

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
  function(details) {
    if (details.url.includes('bet365.com/streamingapi/v2/stream')) {
      return {responseHeaders: [{name: 'Status', value: '504 Gateway Timeout'}]};
    }
  },
  {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
  ["blocking", "responseHeaders"]
);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not a header and webRequest can't change it. If this API is called via `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest` you can override these methods in [page context](/a/9517879) and spoof the response. See [these examples](/q/18310484). You can also inspect/debug Requestly in devtools to see how it does the same.